# How can i login to a website using fingerprint instead of typing user-id and password

Tags: authentication, fingerprint

How can i login to a website using fingerprint  (for example lets take facebook) instead of typing user-id and password ,is there any way i can link my login id and password to my fingerprint and whenever i opened that website , i will just enter my fingerprint and it has to log into my account

NOTE : not for android devices, has to work on personal computers using a fingerprint device

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take a look at Windows Hello for Business [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/webauthnapis)